# Angular4 data validation for the tax rate

Tags: angular, validation

How can I use a correct tax rate validator. tax rate should be "0.08", not "8" or 8%. when user type input filed then only 0.08 this format allow if any other format gives error will display. want to use this in angular4.

Comment: Quick question before I answer, do you know reactive forms ?

Comment: @trichetriche yes, i m using two way databinding in text filed

Comment: Well if it's 2-way binding, you're using `ngModel`, right ?

Comment: @trichetriche, yes using ngModel and here my input code:<input type="text" [ngModel]="location.tax |taxrate" (ngModelChange)="location.tax= $event"  (change)="chnageTax(location._id,location.tax)" (click)="$event.target.select()">

Comment: So you don't know reactive Forms. I'm doing you a piece of code right now, don't move.

Comment: @trichetriche, I know reactive from but i don't use this as i am doing databinding. first I am displaying tax rate from api, if tax rate not exits then enter tax rate

Comment: Why do you use an input of type text, since you expect the user to enter a number?

Comment: @JBNizet  for firstly  data display from api it's format string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that, you can use [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms). They have built-in validators, and you can easily add custom ones to suit your needs. Gladly, there's alrrady one to suite your needs !

First, start by creating variables :

```
myForm: FormGroup;
```

Then, inject the form builder dependency, and create your form :

```
constructor(private FB: FormBuilder) {
  this.myForm = FB.group({
    tax: ['your initial value here', [Validators.pattern(/0\.\d{1,3}/)]]
  });
}
```

Now, you have a pattern validator that says

> The input should start with "0.", then have 1 to 3 figures after the point.

(You can of course change the pattern to suit your need).

Now, in your HTML :

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" novalidate>
  <input type="text" formControlName="tax" [class.invalid]="myForm.hasError('tax', 'pattern')">
</form>
```

This will add the "invalid" class to your input if it doesn't match the pattern.

**EDIT** If you want to do it in your method, use this HTML :

```
<input type="text" (input)="changeTaxrate(this.value)" />
```

In your TS :

```
changeTaxrate(value: string) {
  let match = value.match(/0\.\d{1,3}/);
  if (!match) { return; }
  // Do you code here
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to use without form  because i not using form i want to work this in my called function like i use call changeTaxrate() in change event

Comment: Then do your own solution with a model-driven form or with an input of type number :) I'm advising the reactive forms because (in my opinion), they're much more easier to implement. If you want to help him with your solution, make an answer, but criticizing mine just for the sake of it won't help the OP.

Comment: Well @SalmaKonaGugly, you should have mentioned that in your question, don't you think ? Or at least provided some code ... I'm editing my answer.

Comment: @trichetriche, I am really sorry for not mentioned in question or comment.

Comment: @trichetriche, I find out solution using your second method, need  add extra code as fulfil my requirement. Thanks for your help.